# How to solve the following issues in Windows 10, Error: Could not fork child process: Resource temporarily unavailable (-1). Explain me simple way

Tags: git, git-bash, git-for-windows

I can't use my Git bash in Windows 10. How to resolve the issues. When I tried to use it showing like this," Error: Could not fork child process: Resource temporarily unavailable (-1).
DLL rebasing may be required; see 'rebaseall / rebase --help'"

I don't know, What to do? I want to help me, How to resolve this issues in simple way. Please explain as simple as like easy to understand. Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Error%3A+Could+not+fork+child+process%3A+Resource+temporarily+unavailable+%28-1%29.+DLL+rebasing+may+be+required